# WPF ListBox SelectedItem issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

Can anyone help, lost a lot of time trying to figure this issue out.

I have a ViewModel with following properties

```
    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> OpcoList { get; set; }
    public ListItem SelectedOpco {
        get {
            return _selectedOpco;
        }
        set {
            if (_selectedOpco != null && _selectedOpco.Equals(value)) {
                return;
            }
            var oldValue = _selectedOpco;
            _selectedOpco = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedOpco");  
    }
```

And in my XAML i have

```
    <ListBox Name="listOpco" ItemsSource="{Binding OpcoList}" 
   SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedOpco}">
```

But whenever I set some value to SelectedOpco in my VM it does not show as selected in ListBox.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint or similar to confirm that you're getting all the way through your setter?

Comment: Yes, I did, the weird part is that selection on the ListBox is reflected on the VM but change on the VM is not reflected on ListBox

Comment: That suggests that your `PropertyChanged` event isn't firing correctly.  Can you post the implementation of the `RaisePropertyChanged` call?

Comment: Are you sure that the new `SelectedOpco` is a member of the `OpcoList` collection? You can't do `SelectedOpco = new ListItem(...)`.

Comment: This RaisePropertyChanged is inherited from MVVM Light toolkit ViewModelBase

Comment: Clemens, I think that there lies an issue but I can't pinpoint it. 
Here is how i set the SelectedOpco
        SelectedOpco = OpcoList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == this.SelectedDescriptable.GetVariantValue("OpcoId").ToString());

Comment: Have you checked if the result of SingleOrDefault is not `null`? Could you also try FirstOrDefault? And `ListItem.Value` is actually a string?

Comment: Yes i Have verified that this selects a good ListItem so i have no idea why

Comment: It's kind of paranoid, but in the `SelectedOpco` setter could you also verify that `_selectedOpco` ia actually a member of `OpcoList`?

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try:

1. Simplify the setter to something simpler (it should do what you expect to - check if a different element of the list is selected).

   ```
   set {
       if(_selectedOpco != value) {
           _selectedOpco = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedOpco");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put a break point at the `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedOpco");` line to see if the execution goes there. If yes, check if the class is really marked as `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

   ```
   if(!(this is INotifyPropertyChanged))
        throw new Exception("Not INotifyPropertyChanged");
   ```
3. Try to set the value with:

   ```
   SelectedOpco = OpcoList.FirstOrDefault(); // LastOrDefault
   ```

Good luck!